# Storing numbers as text for VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am aggregating a large amount of data from several workbooks and need to cross-reference several thousand items, perfect job for VLOOKUP.

However, all I get is the lovely #NA error.

The issue of course is type mismatch like always. For some reason, selecting the cells and setting the type to text is not enough, you have to enter into the cell and then hit enter (F2 + Enter, or use the code provided below). Is there a better way to force data to be of a certain type using built in excel functions? I've tried everything from format painter, text to columns, etc. and get no results.

VBA code I used as a work-around:

```
Sub Macro3()
' Select the starting cell, macro will work it's way down the list changing nothing.
'
Dim variable As String
Dim t As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For t = 0 To 500
    variable = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = variable
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Next t

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Excel considers itself knowing it better than you, and whatever you do, if you load something that looks like a number, it becomes one.

What I typically do is put a formula in a helper column which makes it text `=TEXT(A1,"0")`, copy the formula down, and then copy the whole column and `Paste Values` over the original data. You can then toss the helper column.

Comment: This is upsetting, but not unexpected. I'm glad Microsoft, undoubtedly in its attempts to make its software more idiot proof, has again made life more difficult for those who want to use it to its potential. I'll probably just use the helper column since I'm doing this whole process through one big macro. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapusate the cell with a blank string to force the number to text.

In a helper column `=A1 & ""` and copy the column down.  Now when you do a VLOOKUP the number will be trated as text.